# c# GeoCoding from Text to Lat/Long

Tags: c#, mysql, geolocation, geocoding, geo

I'am looking to GeoCode 250k+ Text to Latitude/Longitude daily and don't think using an API service like Google or Bing would work as it would be very expensive.

I already have the relevant data i.e. City/Town names, Country and latitude/longitude data in my Mysql Database. The data has been sourced from Yahoo's YQL service and I have added latitude/longitude values to each of the 6 million results as they did not come with this data.

What would be the best way to get good results. The data that i would be feeding to my app would like the below:

- New York
- Warwick  Midlands
- London, near the railway station
- East Grinstead South East/Southern RH185FR
- Sheffield  Yorkshire  S3 8JB

And the output I would want for each request would be the location name and latitude/latitude values.

Accuracy wise I' am not that concerned as long as its in the area by 25 miles.

I was looking at full-text search engines like elastic search but they seem like overkill for something like this though I did get a test data set running but being more text based i was getting a lot of false results.

Comment: Maybe you can use GeoNames for this: http://www.geonames.org/export/ws-overview.html. Has some webservices that you may ask to get a location.

Comment: @HimBromBeere do you know if this service has an limits?

Comment: As far as I know there is none as it´s an open-service used on OpenStreetMap also.